# C# Facebook sdk Configure Test environment

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

In the docs (http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started), the Configuring the Facebook C# SDK, mentions to change site URL under website settings. I've been looking for this setting and cannot find it. I'm using VS 2010.

The project runs but the handler does not work. Had to upload to our host and it works fine there. I would like to do all of my testing locally, I've been uploading to test, takes debugging out of picture. I did everything like the doc says except the above.

Hmmm, since facebook asks for url of app, do I need to fake it using host file to point to local machine ie 127.0.0.1 myapp.com?

Thanks

Rick

Comment: I could use an answer to this question myself - if I figure it out I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Right, I figured it out:

When the Facebook C# SDK docs refer to the Site URL under the website settings they're referring to the Facebook app settings on the developers console (https://developers.facebook.com/). So to wrap up, the docs recommend entering "http://localhost:[test env port]/" as your app's site URL to allow you to make requests from your development environment.

To my mind that's not a particularly great way to handle things but I guess it will have to do - I'll probably set up a "dev" app that mirrors the live application for development. If anyone has a better suggestion I'm open to better solutions.